# Using MySQL vector with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector, mysql

I have a problem with mysql vector; when I connect to the MySQL table (containing a geometry column), the attribute table is loaded correctly, the map is centered properly but the geometries are not displayed; 
if I save the vector as a shapefile classic or other type, the new layer is loaded and displayed correctly. 
I'm using Windows7 + qgis 2.8 lts

I tested the same procedure in ubuntu 14.04 + qgis 2.8lts and everything works properly.

I believe it depends on GDAL/OGR, someone can help me?

I get the same result (geometry not displayed) even if I load the table console py:

```
from qgis.core import * 
uri = "MySQL:xxx,host=localhost,port=3306,user=root,password=xxx|\ 
layername=xxx" 
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer( uri, "xxx", "ogr" ) 
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

if I select all records of the attribute table, and I use the tool to move the elements (with the edit mode on) when I click on the map all the elements appear in the map and remain visible until I deactivate the edit mode....

Comment: A solution for this bug between QGIS and MySQL.
https://youtu.be/uzbB_pWgB2g